# Cannot get LinkGenerator to create a path to API action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing

I am trying to create a link to an API endpoint from inside a Service - outside of a Controller.

Here is the Controller and its base class. I am using API versioning and Areas in ASP.NET Core.

```
[ApiController]
[Area("api")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]")]
public abstract class APIControllerBase : ControllerBase
{

}

[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class WidgetsController : APIControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}"]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Widget>> Get(Guid id)
    {
        // Action...
    }
}
```

API Versioning configuration:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
        new QueryStringApiVersionReader
        {
            ParameterNames = { "api-version", "apiVersion" }
        },
        new HeaderApiVersionReader
        {
            HeaderNames = { "api-version", "apiVersion" }
        });
});
```

And where I actually try to use LinkGenerator:

```
_linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(
    _accessor.HttpContext,
    action: "Get",
    controller: "Widgets",
    values: new
    {
        id = widget.Id,
        apiVersion = "1.0"
    }
)
```

I've tried all manner of variations for the LinkGenerator. I've used the HttpContext overload, I've used the overload without it, I've included the apiVersion parameter and omitted it, I've removed `[ApiVersion]` from the Controller entirely. Everything always comes back `null`. If I route to a normal MVC Controller like `GetPathByAction("Index", "Home")` I get a URL like I should though, so I'm think it must be related to my API Areas, or versioning setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not specifying the area:

```
_linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(
    _accessor.HttpContext,
    action: "Get",
    controller: "Widgets",
    values: new
    {
        area = "api",
        id = widget.Id,
        apiVersion = "1.0"
    }
)
```

Comment: That works. I hadn't considered Area as a parameter and was thinking the router would map to it on its own.

Comment: Nope. No area is assumed as no area, so it will explicitly not match anything within an area. Works the same as something like `Html.Action` when dealing with areas.

Comment: Makes sense. I originally thought the LinkGenerator methods would have an `area` parameter since I tend to think of Areas as in the same hierarchy as Controllers and Actions.

Comment: Yeah. That's a common assumption. I think it stems from two things: first a lot of this builds on conventions that came from ASP.NET MVC (the `Html.Action` API was kept the same, for instance) and areas were not originally part of ASP.NET MVC, but rather were added in later. Second, eventually, the method signature starts to get bloated with params. Adding a param for area not only adds one more param, but also requires an exponential increase in override signatures. Given that it works with the route values param, there's really no need for that.

Comment: Fun fact, action and controller could technically *also* be specified via the route values param, it's just that it's not typical to do that since there is specific params for those, and at least in the case of the action, there's no signature available where you don't have to at least pass an action.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks Chris but in this case the url will look like that : 
https://localhost:44337/_Settings/Maintenance/InventoryCategories/Edit/1?area=api&apiVersion=1.0
how can it be possible to remove these query strings so the url can be : 
https://localhost:44337/_Settings/Maintenance/InventoryCategories/Edit/1

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps someone else, I had an issue very similar to this but the action was named `GetAsync` and it turns out you cannot reference the action by it's full name "GetAsync", you have to use it without the suffix so just "Get".

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the problem I was having. These implicit name rules really do more harm than good.