# ASP.NET Core Web API - include API version in the links of created entity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, versioning, webapi

I'm in process of implementing HATEOAS principle in my WebAPI project. After a new entity of any given type is added to DB, response should contain not only a newly created entity, but 3 links to GET, PUT and DELETE endpoints in corresponding controller. Also, I use API versioning in endpoints URIs.

So, my controller is decorated with attributes:

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("3.0")]
```

API versioning configuration in Startup.cs

```
services.AddApiVersioning(opt =>
{
    opt.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    opt.DefaultApiVersion = ApiVersion.Default;
    opt.ReportApiVersions = true;
});
```

Method to generate links for entity:

```
public override List<ResourceUri> GetResourceUris(int id, ApiVersion apiVersion)
{
    return new List<ResourceUri>
    {
        new ResourceUri
        {
            Method = "GET",
            Uri = this._linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(
                HttpContext, 
                nameof(GetResourceById), 
                values: new
                {
                    Id = id, 
                    area = "api", 
                    version = apiVersion.ToString()
                })
        },

        new ResourceUri
        {
            Method = "PUT",
            Uri = this._linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(HttpContext, nameof(UpdateItem), values: new { id })
        },

        new ResourceUri
        {
            Method = "DELETE",
            Uri = this._linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(HttpContext, nameof(DeleteItem), values: new { id })
        },

    };
}
```

Section

```
values: new
{
    Id = id, 
    area = "api", 
    version = apiVersion.ToString()
})
```

was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55028147/cannot-get-linkgenerator-to-create-a-path-to-api-action), where it is marked as accepted answer.

However, every time I POST new entity, result is this:

```
{
    "uri": "https://localhost:44386/api/v1/Resources/43?area=api&version=3",
    "method": "GET"
}
```

Area and Version values are only included as query parameters and API version is always set to 'v1' instead of 'v3'.

Giving that

```
AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified
```

is set to True, I'm using a wrong way to provide an ApiVersion to LinkGenerator. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
[Area("api")]
```

to the Controller

Answer (score 0):

This should *just work*. I have a couple of questions though. Which version of the library are you using? This issue has been resolved for a number of years now. Where did `_linkGenerator` come from? Is it directly or indirectly resolved from DI? It's not clear from the information provided.

### Explanation

When you version by URL segment, you must use the `ApiVersionRouteContraint` (which you are). A route parameter has 2 parts: a name and an optional constraint. `{version:apiVersion}` has the name `version` and the constraint key `apiVersion`. You can use whatever name you want for the *name*. The constraint key must match whatever has been registered. `ApiVersioningOptions.RouteConstraintName` defaults to `apiVersion`, but you *can* change it.

Several, simple things happen during constraint matching:

1. The `value` is captured as `IApiVersioningFeature.RawRequestedApiVersion`
2. The `value` is parsed and on:

   1. success it is set as `IApiVersioningFeature.RequestedApiVersion`
   2. failure it doesn't match (e.g. which will eventually lead to `404`)
3. The `key` is captured as `IApiVersioningFeature.RouteParameter`

The last part is what's critical.

The default `LinkGenerator` is not aware of this parameter. Assuming you used the name `version`, the link generator doesn't know how to populate that. You may not have a `version` parameter in your action. More importantly, the model binder for `ApiVersion` is `BindingSource.Special` because it can come from different, and even multiple, locations. The `LinkGenerator` has fallback behavior to put everything it doesn't know what to do with on the query string (which is the behavior you are seeing).

When you call `AddApiVersioning`, it will register or decorate the existing registration for `LinkGenerator`, which is API version-aware. As long as `IApiVersioningFeature.RouteParameter` and `IApiVersioningFeature.RawRequestedApiVersion` are non-empty and do not exist in the `RouteValueDictionary`, they will be added.

There's a couple of caveats:

1. The value is not overwritten by design. If you explicitly set `version` to some value, it will not be processed.
2. If target URL does not also use the name `version`, then link generation will probably be wrong.
3. If you have a mixed style of versioning and you come from a place that does not version by URL and you try to build a link for an endpoint that does, there is no `version` parameter to use.

### Example

Consider the following controller:

```cs
[ApiVersion( 1.0 )]
[Route( "api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]" )]
public class HelloWorldController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet( "{id:int}" )]
    public IActionResult Get( int id, ApiVersion apiVersion ) =>
        Ok( new { Controller = GetType().Name, Id = id } );

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post( ApiVersion apiVersion ) =>
        CreatedAtAction( nameof( Get ), new { id = 42 }, null );
}
```

If you send the request:

```http
POST /api/v1/helloworld/42 HTTP/2
Host: example.api.com
```

You'll get the response:

```http
HTTP/2 201 Created
Location: https://example.api.com/api/v1/helloworld/42
```

which uses the `LinkGenerator` to build the `Location` header field value.

### Conclusion

The fact that the incorrect URL has `v1` as opposed to no value, leads me to believe that route template may have a hardcode value instead of the required route constraint (e.g. `api/v1/Resources/{id}` vs `api/v{version:apiVersion}/Resources/{id}`). That would certainly prevent it from working as intended.

If the `LinkGenerator` is constructed outside of DI, then it is not API version-aware and will also not function as intended. If you need this ability, then you should decorate the instance explicitly using `ApiVersionLinkGenerator`.